# Giving actions on click of leaflet markers created using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, leaflet

I tried to put ajax function calls as response to click on markers in map.
But the links doesn't work (probably because) at time of click, the loop is no longer running.

Code:

```
<script>
function load_map_module(query) {
    markers.clearLayers();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/load-map/',
        type: 'get',
        data: {'key':query.key, 'id':query.id},
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(d) {
            res = d.res
            if (res.length > 0){
                for(i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
                    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(res[i].latitiude, res[i].longitude), {icon: pinkicon, zIndexOffset:1000, riseOnHover:true, riseOffset:1000});
                    marker.bindPopup(res[i].name).openPopup();
                    markers.addLayer(marker);
                    temp_popup = (new L.Popup())
                        .setLatLng(new L.LatLng(res[i].latitiude, res[i].longitude))
                        .setContent("<span style='cursor:pointer;' <a href='#'> onclick="return load_map_module(({'key':'res.key', 'id':{{res.id}}}))">Hiii</a></span>");
                        .openOn(map);
                    marker_list.push(marker);
                    latlng_list.push(new L.LatLng(res[i].latitiude, res[i].longitude));
                }
            }
        }
    });
    map.addLayer(markers);
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your popup's content HTML is invalid, the opening tag for `span` isn't closed properly and you opening `a` tag is closed twice, once right before the onclick attribute. Also your function call in the onclick handler is completely faulty, that's not the way to concatenate strings and variables and you're mixing double quotes and single quotes:

```
.setContent("<span style='cursor:pointer;' <a href='#'> onclick="return load_map_module(({'key':'res.key', 'id':{{res.id}}}))">Hiii</a></span>")

.setContent("<span style='cursor:pointer;'><a href='#' onclick='return load_map_module({key:" + res.key + ", id:" + res.id + "})'>Hiii</a></span>")
```

Also why do you put your popup declaration in parentheses?

```
temp_popup = (new L.Popup())
```

This should work just fine:

```
temp_popup = new L.Popup()
```

Comment: Thank you.  Tried these changes.  Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Without a proper testcase on Plunker or JSFiddle, we're kind of in the dark here. I've mentioned the errors i spotted at first glance. They could have been prevented by using a proper IDE and JSLint plus you must be getting multiple errors in your console window which can be easily debugged and solved with some basic JS knowledge. I'de suggest you do so, and if you can't solve them at least add a testcase on Plunker or JSFiddle and quote the errors you're getting in your console.